# Is it possible to get an interrupt on DMA halfway done STM32f0

Tags: interrupt, stm32, dma

i have a circular DMA that I want to update. Is it possible to get a interrupt when it is halfway done (so i can update the first half)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, simply set the HTIE bit in the appropriate Channel Configuration Register, e.g.

```
DMA1_Channel2->CCR |= DMA_CCR_HTIE;
```

for channel 2, before starting the transfer. Don't forget to set the priority, and enable the interrupt.

In the interrupt handler, check if it's indeed a Half Transfer Interrupt, clear the flag, then do whatever processing is necessary.

```
void DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQHandler(void) {
    if(DMA1->ISR & DMA_ISR_HTIF2) {
        DMA1->IFCR = DMA_IFCR_CHTIF2;
        memcpy(here, there, length/2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no channels any more only streams.

may be read the bit

```
READ_BIT(DMA1->HISR ,DMA_HISR_HTIF5);
```

or maybe something like this?

```
DMA1_Stream5-> CRR |= DMA_HISR_HTIF5;
```